# Can not update database through DataGridView - no errors

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

One button and datagridview. If button text1 ("Edit database") datagridview reads into database, if button text2 ("ACCEPT CHANGES") datagridview writes into database, but the latter can not happen, no matter what I do. No errors just doesn't make changes to database file.

```
            Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\PD_Z.mdb"
        Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM ZARADE"
        Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
        Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)
        OleDBConn1.Open()
        OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "ZARADE")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name)

        If Button2.Text = "Edit database" Then
            DataGridView1.ReadOnly = False
            Button2.Text = "ACCEPT CHANGES"
            Button2.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            Button1.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False

        Else
    Button2.Text = "Edit database"
            DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
            Button2.ForeColor = Color.Black
            Button1.Enabled = True
            ComboBox1.Enabled = True

            'Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter1) ' THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK
            '  cb.QuotePrefix = "["
            '  cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
            '  OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE"))

            Using con = New OleDbConnection(ConnString) ' THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK TOO
                Me.Validate()
                OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE"))
                DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
            End Using
            DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
            OleDBConn1.Close()
```

This code is in Button_click event.

Answer (score 0):

after you executed

```
OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "ZARADE")
```

all rows in your dataset have RowWtate = Unchanged ... so when you call Update(DataSet1....) there is nothing to update ... check the return value ... I guess it will be 0 because no rows have been affected ...

Comment: So, what should I do. I thought first click reads database into datagrid view and second click writes into database. Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achive ... if you write directly after reading there will be no changes to be written ... standard workflow would be to read from db, attach to grid, make changes inside the grid by editing cell values (that will change to rowstates automatically) and then update to db (for example in button click event)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain. First click activates/imports data into datagridview and enables datagridview for editing "DataGridView1.ReadOnly = False", then I have mouse click event, every click on "cell" puts "X" value into it or deletes it if there are "X" already there. Then when editing is finished. Another click on the same button writes changes from datagridview ("X"s) into database. This code above is only button click event, that should populate datagridview and enable it for editing and another click to write those changes into database.

I hope I am not confusing.

Comment: i understand ... maybe you could move the part where you Fill DataSet1 into the if block ... so that you don't call Fill (and overwrite your changes) before you call Update ...

Comment: Nope, that didn't work out. I have to populate database first so that I am able to see database contents in datagridview and so that I can add values, then update. If I put Fill DataSet1 into the if block I get this error : "Index was out of range Must be non-negative and less then size of the collection Parameter name index"

Comment: i'm sure you've put the two lines following the Fill statement (DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE")       DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name)) inside the if block too ... it would not make sense to access a table inside a collection before it was created ... and it's created by the Fill statement ...

Comment: Sorry, for bothering you again, but now (after putting all three lines inside if block) datagridview is being populated but I still get an error when changing table and clicking again for database update : Value cannot be null, Parameter name : dataTable